# Unable to pull ubuntu image using docker on windows host

Tags: docker

I have installed docker on windows 10.

Docker version:

```
Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4
```

I tried to pull latest ubuntu and ubuntu:16.04 using the bellow two commands

```
docker pull ubuntu

docker pull ubuntu:16.04
```

But I am getting the below error.

```
docker pull ubuntu
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu
no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the manifest list entries
```

So is there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can't run linux images with a windows daemon.

If you are running [Docker for Windows](https://www.docker.com/docker-windows), it gives you the ability to [switch](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#switch-between-windows-and-linux-containers) between running a Windows Docker daemon and a Linux Docker daemon inside a hyper-v VM.

To run Linux workloads, make sure you have chosen "Switch to Linux Containers" in the Docker for Windows whale icon menu.

Answer (score 0):

please follow the Docker tutorial [here](https://blog.docker.com/2017/09/preview-linux-containers-on-windows/)

In this case the problem is it requires adding the `--experimental` flag when starting `dockerd.exe`.